# ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path

Tags: ansible

I trying to create a simple paybook with a common role.  Unfortunately I get stymied by ansible.   I have looked up and down the internet for solution for this error.

The setup:
I am running ansible 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

directory structure:

```
~/Ansible_Do
 playbook.yml
 inventory  (hosts file) 
    /roles
      /common 
        /defaults
            main.yml   (other variables)
        /tasks
            main.yml
            richard_e.yml
        /vars
            vars_and_stuff.yml   (vault)
```

I have a simple playbook.yml

```
---
# My playbook 1
- hosts: test

- name: Go to common role to run tasks.
  roles:
    - common

  tasks:
  - name: echo something
    shell: echo $(ip addr | grep inet)
...
```

I run this command to start the playbook:

```
~/Ansible_Do$ ansible-playbook -vv --vault-id @prompt -i ~/Ansible_Do/inventory playbook.yml
```

I enter the vault password continuing the playbook.

The playbook starts pulls facts from the test group of servers.  Then reads the role and works to /roles/common.  That calls the /common/tasks/main.yml file.  This is where the error happens.

The error appears to have been in '/home/~/Ansible_Do/roles/common/tasks/main.yml': line 8, column 3

```
# Common/tasks file
---
- name: Bring variable from vault
  include_vars:
    file: vars_and_stuff.yml
    name: My_password

- name: Super Richard   <======  Error 
  become: yes  
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ My_password }}"

- import_tasks: ./roles/common/tasks/ricahrd_e.yml
...
```

The ./roles/common/tasks/ricahrd_e.yml is a simple testing task.

```
---
- name: say hi
  debug:
    msg: "Active server."
...
```

The error on "- name".  I have checked online and in the Ansible docs to see if there is a key I'm missing.  I found an example for include_vars in a /role/tasks  (https://gist.github.com/halberom/ef3ea6d6764e929923b0888740e05211) showing proper syntax (I presume) in a simple role.  The code works as parts, but not together.

I have reached what I can understand.  I feel that is error is utterly simple and I am missing something (forest for the trees).

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly what it says, except the "module name" is not misspelled in your case, but missing altogether.

This...

```
- name: Super Richard   <======  Error 
  become: yes  
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ My_password }}"
```

... is not a valid task definition, it does not declare an action.
An action in Ansible is a call to a module, hence "misspelled module name".
The error comes after `name`, because that's where Ansible  expects the name of the "module" that you want to call, e.g. `shell` in your first example.

You are probably assuming that `become` is a "module", but it is not.
It is a "playbook keyword", in this case applied on the task level, which has the effect that you become another user *for this task only*.
But as the task has no action, you get this error.

See docs:
[Playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html)
[Understanding privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation)

Comment: I can see that misinterpretation of "become".   I will look at using become away from the tasks list file.   I'll at the main playbook and work around that.

Comment: Generally I would recommend putting it only on tasks that actually need it. You can mix and match it also, i.e. set `become: yes` on a playbook, and override with `become: no` on a task level.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of work I got the playbook to work.  Knowing that 'become' is not a task was the start.  I also found out how to pull the proper vars from the vault.

```
# My first playbook 1
- hosts: test
  become: yes

  vars_files:
  - ./roles/common/vars/vars_and_stuff.yml

  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ My_password }}"

  roles:
    - common

  tasks:
  - name: echo something
    shell: echo $(ip addr | grep inet)
```

The vars file access the vault and then `vars:` pulls the password used by `become`.  With `become` in force I ran the other tasks in the `common` role with a last standalone task.  Lastly, don't try to `- name:` at the top level of the playbook as it trigger a hosts undefined error.